# Rails error when firing up a cloned API - ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, api, ruby-on-rails-5

As the title says, I clones a rails API. I tried to follow the steps in this article from point 2 onwards https://dev.to/w3ndo/a-checklist-for-setting-up-a-cloned-rails-application-locally-5468 but I keep getting the same error from db:setup onwards.

[image]

Please help!

I have tried googling the answer and phoning a friend.

I have tried rails db:setup, rails db:seed, rails db:create, rails db:migrate.

Update: So I found I was getting this error because the db owner was listed as the original owner in the repo but when I typed psql in terminal and located the db, the owner was listed as me.

I was able to change this using PGadmin 4 and type in the original owner as the db owner.

Comment: Do you have a Postgres Database instance installed on your computer and running on port 5432 (usual port for pg) ? Basically it just says it cannot connect do database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found I was getting this error because the db owner was listed as the original owner in the repo but when I typed psql in terminal and located the db, the owner was listed as me.

I was able to change this using PGadmin 4 and type in the original owner as the db owner.

Answer (score 0):

You want to initialize the postgres db, which doesn't quite come for free. I recommend using sqlite3 until you need a production db. If the clone calls for PG, then:

1. (user)     $ `sudo su - postgres`
2. (postgres) $ `createuser --interactive`
3. (local)    $ `sudo systemctl restart postgresql`
4. (local)    $ `bundle exec rails db:create:all`

$ `pg_isready` tells you at a glance if posgtres server/cluster is online.

```bash
$ pg_isready
/tmp:5432 - accepting connections
```

If it gets frustrating, change the `config/database.yml` to the default version, remove pg gem if possible, add sqlite3. Then simple `rake db:migrate` after creating or adding an [environment].sqlite3 file to db/

```rb
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Comment: Thanks Tidelake, I'm working on this project with a partner who creted the backend using postgres. I cloned his repo. Will me switching to SQLite cause issues for him?

Some advice I got elsewhere was 
"On googling the error from the first one "rails db setup library not loaded libpq.5" it looks like because you've reinstalled postgresql, you'll need to uninstall and reinstall the pg gem: "

However this hasn't worked for me neither

Comment: create a local development branch using: `git checkout -b local` and then you can add database.yml to your local `.gitignore` file, if needed

Comment: Thanks Tidelake, as my partner had created the backend, the issue was arising because the owners of the database didn't match when I cloned his repo. So I accessed PSQL and used CREATE USER

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

Thank you for the help. I was able to find out as my partner had created the backend, the issue was arising because the owners of the database didn't match when I cloned his repo.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).